# How to change FieldSize to be the same as dropdown menu width in PopupMenu?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I've tried the following code to change the `FieldSize` but I can't make it equal the actual value of `MenuSize` and I tried to remove first `Delimiter` but I can't.

```
ActionMenu["PopupMenu", 
 Flatten@Table[{Delimiter, lable1}, {ittration3, 1, 3}], 
 Appearance -> "PopupMenu", Enabled -> True, 
 Background -> RGBColor[0.235, 0.486, 0.768], FieldSize -> 6]
```

And please tell me how to change the background color of the field.

Comment: Use `Riffle[{"Label1", "Label2", "Label3"}, Delimiter]` to introduce delimiters only *between* labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mathematica 9 (OSX), `Background` doesn't colour the default `PopupMenu` button, it just colours the background around the button.  Here's a manual version:

```
act = Rest[
   Flatten@Table[{Delimiter, "label " <> ToString[i]}, {i, 1, 3}]];

am = ActionMenu["PopupMenu", act, Appearance -> None, 
   Background -> RGBColor[0.235, 0.486, 0.768], 
   ImageSize -> {150, 32}, FieldSize -> 10.83];

popup = Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {170, 32}],
    Inset[am, {75, 16}, Center, {150, 32}],
    Inset[Style["\[FilledUpTriangle]", Black, 9], {160, 21}, Center],
    Inset[Style["\[FilledDownTriangle]", Black, 9], {160, 11}, Center],
    Black, Line[{{0, 1}, {169, 1}, {169, 32}, {0, 32}, {0, 1}}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 170}, {0, 32}}, ImageSize -> 170];

popup
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your idea but i want that dropdown list size should be same as `PopupMenu`'s size and i want dropdown marker next to string("PopupMenu") .

Comment: @niren - I have edited my answer, matching the sizes using `FieldSize` for the popup fields, and `ImageSize` for the button. I also included a dropdown marker.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `PopupMenu`. Try this code.

```
popupMenuValue = "PopupMenu";
{PopupMenu[Dynamic[popupMenuValue], 
    {"Label1", "Label2", "Label3"}, 
    "",
    Row[{Panel[Style["PopupMenu", White], 
                  Background -> RGBColor[0.235, 0.486, 0.768],
                  Alignment -> Center,
                  ImageSize -> {180, 60}], 
         Panel[Style["∨", White], 
                  Background -> RGBColor[0.235, 0.486, 0.768], 
                  ImageSize -> {30, 60},
                  Alignment -> Center]}], 
    MenuStyle -> {25, Blue}, Alignment -> Center, Appearance -> None], 
Dynamic[popupMenuValue]}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you intend to accomplish by wrapping your `PopupMenu` expression in a list with `Dynamic[popupMenuValue]`.

Comment: what I am trying ,dynamically we can do all computation's by using `PopupMenu` instead of `ActionMenu`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean you want? Use `Full` to obtain the Full size

```
act = Table[{Delimiter, lable1}, {ittration3, 1, 3}];

ActionMenu["PopupMenu",
 Flatten@act,
 Appearance -> "PopupMenu",
 Enabled -> True,
 Background -> RGBColor[0.235, 0.486, 0.768],
 FieldSize -> Full]
```

[image]